# Cannot autoload routing from Bundles

Tags: php, symfony, routes, bundle, autoload

I have a problem wuth autoloading routing from bundles. I have routing.yml file in folder: Bundle\UsersBundle\Resources\config. I am loading routes as they say in Symfony cookbook(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html). And it all works great with one bundle but when I add another bundle to AppKernel it does not load new routing. It looks like every bundle needs separate entry in main routing.yml(which is exactly what I don't want to have). Every RoutesLoader service has set right tags and container is loading this services properly.

**routing.yml:** (this config works but it needs that RouteLoader from another bundle have to return another type - "bundle_routes_2" - when it returns "bundle_routes" routing is not loaded)

```
bundles_routes:
    resource: .
    type: bundle_routes

bundles_routes_2:
    resource: .
    type: bundle_routes_2
```

To be more specific - for example I have 3 bundles - UsersBundle, PermissionsBundle and GroupsBundle. Every bundle has routing in its Resources folder(*bundle_folder*/Resources/config/routing.yml). Every bundle has RoutesLoader class which look like that:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UsersBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class UsersRoutesLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();
        $resource = "@AcmeUsersBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml";
        $type = "yaml";
        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);
        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === "bundle_routes";
    }
}
```

And main routing file looks lik that:

```
acme_bundles_routes:
    resource: .
    type: bundle_routes
```

But it works only for one bundle. I have to change routing.yml to:

```
acme_bundles_routes:
        resource: .
        type: bundle_routes
acme_bundles_routes_2:
        resource: .
        type: bundle_routes_2
acme_bundles_routes_3:
        resource: .
        type: bundle_routes_3
```

And every RoutesLoader have to return correspondig type.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a custom loader?

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-include-external-resources

Your parent `routing.yml` should contain:

```
AcmeBundle:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Since you want to have various routing files, you can then have (in `routing.yml`):

```
admin_routes:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resource/config/routes/admin.yml"
user_routes:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resource/config/routes/user.yml"
```

And so on and so forth. Inside any of these bundle yml files you'd contain your path definitions.

Comment: But in my application bundles will by loaded dynamically according to user permissions and thats why I don't want to declare every route in main routing but only bundle will load its routes.

Comment: You're creating more complications than are required. It'd be no less performant to use the default autoloader and permit routes based on roles. As it's not just the routing you need to worry about. What about services, and definitions in your `AppKerenl.php`?